# Setting Background Color CMDIFrameWnd

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc, colors

Is there a way to change the color of the background for a MDIParent windows in MFC (2005)?

I have tried intercepting ON_WM_CTLCOLOR AND ON_WM_ERASEBKGND but neither work. OnEraseBkgnd does work, but then it gets overwritten by the standard WM_CTL color.

Cheers

Comment: dude, didn't i give the actual answer rather than a link to an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CMDIFrameWnd is actually covered up by another window called the MDIClient window. Here is a Microsoft article on how to subclass this MDIClient window and change the background colour. I just tried it myself and it works great.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/129471

Answer (score 4):

Create a class deriving CWnd (CClientWnd for example)

In your CWnd-derived class handle

```
afx_msg BOOL OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC);
afx_msg void OnPaint(void);
afx_msg void OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy);
```

You need the following message map entries:

```
ON_WM_ERASEBKGND()
ON_WM_PAINT()
ON_WM_SIZE()
```

In OnEraseBkgnd just return TRUE, you'll do all of the work in OnPaint

In OnPaint, do whatever you like. To fill with a color, you could do

```
CBrush brush;
brush.CreateSolidBrush(COLORREF(RGB( 80, 160, 240 )));

CRect clientRect;
GetClientRect(clientRect);

CPaintDC dc(this);
dc.FillRect(clientRect, &brush);
```

In OnSize, call the base class, then invalidate to force a repaint:

```
CWnd::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);
Invalidate(FALSE);
```

---

In your mainframe, declare a member CClientWnd (m_clientWnd for example)

In your mainframe's OnCreate, first call the superclass, then

```
m_clientWnd.SubclassWindow(m_hWndMDIClient);
```

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a simple solution to this problem in VS2008 at least:

In

CMainFrame::OnPaint()

{

..

// get the dc of the background window

CWnd* pWnd = CWnd::FromHandle(m_hWndMDIClient) ;

CPaintDC dc1(pWnd) ;

//and then draw or bitblt in this DC

}

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here, but try handling ON_WM_PAINT.